# Reading error messages in bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, jruby

I'm trying to run a `jruby -S rake db:migrate` operation.

This results in an error, which exceeds the number of lines my bash terminal holds, so I can't see the most relevant lines, and I'm stuck with ~1000 lines of:

```
....
org/jruby/runtime/Block.java:89:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:261:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249:in `call19'
org/jruby/RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.gen:-1:in `call'
org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:216:in `call'
org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:212:in `call'
org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:202:in `call'
org/jruby/ast/CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
....
```

I tried `jruby -S rake db:migrate > migrate.out` but the error messages still appear on my terminal and the contents of `migrate.out` is

```
==  ChangeFieldsOnFoo: migrating ========================================
-- remove_column(:foos, :bar)
```

Surely there must be a way to read this error message!

Comment: `bash` is a [*shell*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/info), not a *terminal*. What is your [*terminal*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/terminal/info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tie [`stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stderr/info)(`2`) to [`stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stderr/info)(`1`) using `2>&1` and pipe (`|`) the output through a "pager" such as [`less`](http://www.gnu.org/software/less/) to keep it on the screen until you have finished with it:

```
jruby -S rake db:migrate 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: Nice, detailed response, sir.  You approached it in the better way, while I only explained how to log it to a file.  It also looks like you beat me by one second.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `jruby -S rake db:migrate >> migrate.out 2>&1`  This will redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to a single file.